# GitEye - How to connect to remote repository on sftp server?

Tags: git, collabnet, giteye

I try to connect to my remote repository on a sftp server.

[image: GitEye]

But I always get "Transport Error".

[image: Transport Error]

> An error occured when trying to contact sftp://fooBar/.git. See the
>   error log for more details.
>
> Possible reasons:
>
> - Incorrect URL
> - No network connection (e.g. wrong proxy settings)

I am using no proxy. The connection works via FileZilla without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of support for git clone over sftp:// which is basically what you are asking for here.  The Git client in GitEye fundamentally comes from the Eclipse Git client, which use the JGit library for Git operations.  These would have to support sftp for GitEye to support this.  A quick Google search does not reveal anything that makes this seem likely.